How do I restart the timer when switching a case status back to In Progress after receiving the required information from the customer
A case is created with the status In Progress which starts the timer. Additional information is required from the customer and the status is set to Awaiting Info From Customer. This cancels the timer. Once the information is received from the customer, the status is set back to In Progress but the timer does not start up again. How can I solve this issue?
I have looked at configurations within the SLA settings but cannot seem to find anything other than pause and resume. Also looked at settings in the Customer Service Admin Centre but cant find anything there either
